# JQuery Validation Plugin Remote Validation Error always fires

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

On my home page I have a log in modal that asks for the users email address and password through a basic form. When the email address is entered I have a remote validation that checks to see if the email address is in my blacklisted table in my DB. But the remote error fires off no matter if the PHP returns false or true and will not let the form submit, even if the PHP returns true. All of the validation works correct except for the remote. I can not seem to fix this problem and I have looked all over and nothing I find can solve this problem.

Home jQuery

```
$(function(){
$("#frmSignIn").validate({
        rules: {
            InputEmailAddress: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote:"scripts/blacklist.php"
            },  
            InputPassword: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 20                   
            }
        },
        messages: {
            InputEmailAddress:{
                required:"Don't forget your email address!",
                email:"Please enter a valid email address",
                remote:"This email address has been backlisted"
            },
            InputPassword:{
                required:"Please enter your password",
                minlength:"Password must be longer than 3 characters",
                maxlength:"Password can not be longet than 20 characters"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(){
            var data = $("#frmSignIn").serialize();
            $.post('posted.php', data, function(o){
                console.log(o);
            },'json');
        }
});
});
```

PHP

I will add the actual table check after I get this working

```
$email = $_GET['InputEmailAddress'];
$valid = true;
echo json_encode($valid);
```

Comment: Have you seen the request response in you Firedebug or chrome developper tools, ie developper tools ... ?

Comment: Yes firebug, it returns what it is supposed to true/false but the error message in jquery still fires

Comment: If you use the `submitHandler` properly by including its `form` argument, `submitHandler: function(form){...`, you can simply do this:  `$(form).serialize()`

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that  remote:'scripts/blacklist.php' was in single ''

Soon as I changed it to double quotes "scripts/blacklist.php" it works fine...

If anyone knows why I would love to know so I can understand, but problem solved!

Comment: I do not understand what was the issue. Please past the code.

Comment: The issue was the remote error remote:"This email address has been blacklisted" fired no matter what. But it was apparently because the rule remote call was not in double quotes

Comment: Add the javascript that you have correct. Was it on the PHP side or Javacript. Be more precise.

Comment: I edited it it was the JS  remote:"This email address has been backlisted"

Comment: The URL is already surrounded by double quotes in your OP and JavaScript does not care if it's single or double quotes. In other words, the code shown in your OP, even with single quotes, would not cause the problem you describe.  Your problem was elsewhere.

Comment: I updated the question after I figured it out